# "ON UPDATE" equivalent for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want a create a table that has a column `updated_date` that is updated to **SYSDATE** every time any field in that row is updated. How should I do this in Redshift?

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating table definition like below, that will make sure whenever you `insert` the record, it populates `sysdate`.

```
create table test(
id integer not null,
update_at timestamp DEFAULT SYSDATE);
```

Every time field update?
Remember, **Redshift is DW solution, not a simple database**, hence `updates should be avoided or minimized`.

> UPDATE= DELETE + INSERT

Ideally instead of updating any record, you should be deleting and inserting it, so takes care of `update_at` population while updating which is eventually, `DELETE+INSERT`.

Also, most of use ETLs, you may using `stg_sales` table for populating you date, then also, above solution works, where you could do something like below.

```
DELETE from SALES where id in (select Id from stg_sales);

INSERT INTO SALES select id from  stg_sales;
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't support UPSERTs, so you should load your data to a temporary/staging table first and check for IDs in the main tables, which also exist in the staging table (i.e. which need to be updated).

Delete those records, and INSERT the data from the staging table, which will have the new `updated_date`.

Also, don't forget to run VACUUM on your tables every once in a while, because your use case involves a lot of DELETEs and UPDATEs.

Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html) for additional info.